# Moving text with Word VBA to specific position - something like selection.movedown until?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to cut and paste a block of text in Word using VBA, to move it to a very specific position.  The initial block is nicely defined by two strings (##BT and ##ID) that I can find with wildcards, cut, and paste one line down.  I have that working:

```
'Find the item text strings
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "##BT*##ID"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    '.Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With

'Cut, move, and paste them   
While Selection.Find.Execute
'Move back 4 spaces to remove the ##ID which I don't need (only a boundary)
Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-4
Selection.Cut
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
Selection.Paste
Wend
```

But instead of just simply moving one paragraph down, I want to find the next instance of the string ##BT and paste it there.  Based on some Googling, I tried saving the first Selection as a string, finding the next selection (##BT), and then doing an insert before.  Here is my attempt (replacing the second block of code above).

```
'Cut, move, and paste them
Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-4    
BigString = Selection.Text
While Selection.Find.Execute
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "##BT"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = False
End With

'Paste in the string
Selection.InsertBefore (BigString)
Wend
```

This, however, just inserts a blank line before the first ##BT over and over ad infinitum.  I confirmed the issue by making BigString just 'xyz' and infinity pasting still happened, so the issue is in the finding of the next ##BT.

Any idea how to achieve my goal?  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: How many occurrences of the pattern do you have? and how do you want to group them? Do you want to group all of them at the last position, or just two by two?

Comment: 200 occurences.  Just want to move one by one, only one step down just before the next occurrence, before moving that one down towards the third, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure I follow exactly what you're trying to do, but...

When working in Word, and especially when using FIND, it's a good idea to work with RANGES instead of Selection. You can have only one selection, but you can have multiple Range objects. So, you can execute Find on one Range, store the first "found" in a different Range, then Find again, collapse the "found" to the beginning point, then assign the content of the "storage" Range to that point.

The code would look something like this:

```
Dim rngFind as Word.Range
Dim rngStoreIt as Word.Range
Dim rngInsert as Word.Range
Dim bFound as Boolean

Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.Content
With rngFind.Find
    .Text = "##BT"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = False
    bFound = .Execute
End With
If bFound Then
   Set rngStoreIt = rngFind.Duplicate
   rngFind.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'So don't find the same spot again
   rngFind.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End 'extend to end of doc
   'Repeat the find - you may need to change how you code this...
   Do While rngFind.Find.Execute
      Set rngInsert = rngFind.Duplicate
      rngInsert.Collapse wdCollapseStart
      rngInsert.FormattedText = rngStoreIt.FormattedText
      Set rngStoreIt = rngFind.Duplicate
      rngFind.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'So don't find the same spot again
      rngFind.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End 'extend to end of doc
   Loop
End If
```

Comment: After many many hours of searching, you've finally solved my issues Cindy.  It wasn't so much in making a separate range object (which I'd tried, though perhaps wrong).  But in those last two lines of rngFind.Collapse wdCollapseEnd  and rngFind.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End.  Otherwise if I replaced the first found response then searched again, it would not find any more values unless I reset my selection area to the entire document.  Much appreciated.